# R: Predicting the probability of highest outcome

Tags: r, probability, prediction

I'm relatively new to coding - I've been trying to teach myself R as a hobby, and I've dreamed up this question.  In fact, I just created an account to ask this question!  (I'm also a teacher, which is why I made up this example...)

The Data:

```
                    Test 6  Test 5  Test 4  Test 3  Test 2  Test 1  Pre-test    Attendance
    Student 1               81      82      81      82      83      9           1
    Student 2               84      80      82      80      85      10          0
    Student 3               63      71      70      75      84      7           1
    Student 4               77      82      67      NA      NA      6           1
    Student 5               70      73      73      61      78      8           1
    Student 6               87      89      85      85      88      5           1
    Student 7               72      68      79      60      74      8           0
    Student 8               77      79      71      73      NA      7           1
    Student 9               73      66      70      70      85      10          1
    Student 10              60      62      65      67      61      9           1
```

The task:

I want to use the data to predict **Test 6 Scores**.  Well, that's relatively easy.  Rather, I want to *figure out the probability that each respective student will score the highest in the class on Test 6*.  So, based on this data, what is the probability that Student 1 will score the highest on Test 6?  Student 2?  Etc...

I do not know which function in R will do this for me.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

P.S.  Is it possible to do this *and* use a different number of predictors for each student?  (Notice the NAs I have within the data.)  That would be ideal.  Or, do I first need to clear the NAs so that everybody has exactly 7 predictors?

Comment: What you are probably looking for is an introduction to regression and not a `R` specific answer. Try this (https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) Coursera course

Comment: A simple naïve Bayes model could be applicable for such a situation. There are lots of resources on the web and in the literature on the topic. No need to attend a course,

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate problems here. (1) For each student, compute a probability distribution for their score on the next test, given any scores available for their previous tests. For this part, it isn't necessary that they all have scores for the same tests. (2) Given the probability distributions from the first step, for each student, compute the probability that they have a score greater than that of any other student. I suppose to be careful you have to account for ties, but maybe you can ignore that for now.

For (1) you can apply any of many regression models. You will need to represent the output as a probability distribution; the simplest is to assume Gaussian errors and use the residual (left-over, unaccounted) variance. Many more complicated approaches are possible.

For (2), this is a fairly straightforward probability calculation. The topic you want to look for is called "order statistics".

You might get more interest in this question on stats.stackexchange.com.